# creating sitemap using jsp/servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to create jsp page which has various links. I am doing this through

`out.print("<a href='/foldername/abc.jsp'>Click here to go to next page</a>");`

But instead of

`Click here to go to next page`

I want to fetch names from different jsp or servlet page.
How can this be done ... I am not getting any solution and totally new to this

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for creating sitemap use XML document, then create link. You maybe want some automatic tools like these:

https://code.google.com/p/googlesitemapgenerator/ 

http://www.web-site-map.com/ 

https://xmlsitemapgenerator.org/sitemap-generator.aspx

and it is not important about jsp, php or aspx technology

Comment: i wanted to fetch the data from database for different pages. For Eg: when i click on one link i want to fetch results from database and display it.